# How to show that $A^\circ= \{x\mid x \textrm{ is an interior point of } A\}$ is an open set?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Let $A$ be an arbitrary metric space.
>
> $$A^\circ= \{x\mid x \textrm{ is an interior point of } A\}$$
>
> Show that $A^\circ$ is an open set.

I tried to make a contradiction argument by arguing that if $A^O$ was not open it must have a boundary point $a^O\in A^O$ (I assume the sets are not empty or the universe set) and then by construction of $A^O$ there must exist two balls $B(a^O,r/2) \subseteq B(a^O,r)\subseteq A$ which has at least  one element $x$ from $A\setminus A^O$. But then $B(x,r/2)\subseteq A$ is an open ball in $A$ and $x$ should be in $A^O$ and not in $A\setminus A^O$.  $\Rightarrow\Leftarrow\quad$

Is this a valid proof or just rambling?

Thanks in advance

Comment: By "arbitrary set" do you mean "arbitrary subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ for some $n>0$"? Or something else?

Comment: What is your definition of an `open set`?

Comment: A subset A of a metric space is open if it does not contain any of its boundary points.  A point x is a boundary point in A if the ball B(x,r) for all r>0 contains points in A and its compliment $A^C$. Do I have to restrict myself to a subset of $ℝ^n$, i was thinking about any metric space.

Comment: Ah, so it's a subset of a metric space! You should edit this information into your question. (Also, if you don't want to restrict yourself to $\mathbb R^n$, why did you add the (real-analysis) tag?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you're on the right track, but consider a simpler proof:

Any element $x \in A^{\circ}$ has an open ball $B(x,r_x)$ around it contained in $A$. Thus the union of all such balls is open. Clearly we have $A^{\circ} \subset \cup_{x} B(x,r_x)$. Conversely, if $y \in \cup_{x} B(x,r_x)$, then $y \in B(x,r_x)$ for some $x$. Since the ball is open, there exists a smaller ball around $y$ also contained in $A$. It follows that $A^{\circ} = \cup_{x} B(x,r_x)$, so $A^{\circ}$ is open.